# Android: Scale TextView background image to Fit XY

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have the following textview which uses a simple navbar png file as its background image.
Here's the code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The problem is that on bigger screens the navbar doesn't scale horizontally to fit the screen, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The android:background set to a `TextView` (*in this context*) doesn't have the attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` (or any other value for that matter). That attribute is found on `ImageViews` and `ImageButtons`.

That being said, I would make 2 suggestions for your current situation.

1. Change the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. Naturally the drawable set to the TextView will respect the width of the TextView. I am merely speculating (*no screenshot in the OP*) that the content isn't wide enough on larger display to fill the width.
2. If you aren't doing so already, use either a [Shape Drawable XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) or a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). This will ensure consistent quality across multiple screen sizes.

*If I am completely wrong, post a screen shot. That will make things clearer. ;-)*

Answer (score 14):

Put an imageview behind the TextView and make it's size correspond to the size of the TextView using android:align...:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@id/titleNameText"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@id/titleNameText"
               android:layout_alignRight="@id/titleNameText"
               android:layout_alignTop="@id/titleNameText"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:src="@drawable/navbar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `android:layout_height="50dp"` in order to make view 'highier', try for example `match_parent` instead of `50dp`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [nine patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for background images. Hope this will help you.